# Gem Resque Error - Undefined "method perform" after Overriding it form the super class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, mechanize, resque

First of all Thanks for you all for helping programmers like me with your valuable inputs in solving day to day issues.

This is my first question in stack overflow as I am experiencing this problems from almost one week.

WE are building a crawler which crawls the specific websites and extract the contents from it, we are using mechanize to acheive this , as it was taking loads of time we decided to run the crawling process as a background task using resque with redis gem , but while sending the process to background I am experiencing the error as the title saying,

my code in lib/parsers/home.rb

```
require 'resque'
require File.dirname(__FILE__)+"/../index"
class Home < Index
Resque.enqueue(Index , :page )

def self.perform(page)

super (page)


search_form = page.form_with :name=>"frmAgent"
resuts_page = search_form.submit
total_entries = resuts_page.parser.xpath('//*[@id="PagingTable"]/tr[2]/td[2]').text

if total_entries =~ /(\d+)\s*$/
  total_entries = $1
else
  total_entries = "unknown"
end
start_res_idx = 1
while true
  puts "Found #{total_entries} entries"
  detail_links = resuts_page.parser.xpath('//*[@id="MainTable"]/tr/td/a')
  detail_links.each do |d_link|
    if d_link.attribute("class")
      next
    else
      data_page = @agent.get d_link.attribute("href")
      fields = get_fields_from_page data_page
      save_result_page page.uri.to_s, fields
      #break
    end
  end

  site_done

 rescue Exception => e
 puts "error: #{e}"
 end
end
```

and the superclass in lib/index.rb is

```
require 'resque'
require 'mechanize'
require 'mechanize/form'


class Index

@queue = :Index_queue


def initialize(site)
@site = site
@agent = Mechanize.new
@agent.user_agent = Mechanize::AGENT_ALIASES['Windows Mozilla']
@agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
@rows_parsed = 0
@rows_total = 0
rescue Exception => e
log "Unable to login: #{e.message}"
end


 def run
  log "Parsing..."
  url = "unknown"
  if @site.url
  url = @site.url
  log "Opening #{url} as a data page"
  @page = @agent.get(url)
  #perform method should be override in subclasses
  @data = self.perform(@page)
  else
  #some sites do not have "datapage" URL
  #for example after login you're already on your very own datapage
  #this is to be addressed in 'perform' method of subclass
  @data = self.perform(nil)
  end


 rescue Exception=>e
 puts "Failed to parse URL '#{url}', exception=>"+e.message
 set_site_status("error "+e.message)
 end
 #overriding method
 def self.perform(page)
 end

 def save_result_page(url, result_params)
   result = Result.find_by_sql(["select * from results where site_id = ? AND ref_code = ?", @site.id, utf8(result_params[:ref_code])]).first
   if result.nil?

  result_params[:site_id] = @site.id
  result_params[:time_crawled] = DateTime.now().strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  result_params[:link] = url
  result = Result.create result_params
  else
  result.result_fields.each do |f|
    f.delete
  end
  result.link = url
  result.time_crawled = DateTime.now().strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  result.html = result_params[:html]
  fields = []
  result_params[:result_fields_attributes].each do |f|
    fields.push ResultField.new(f)
  end
  result.result_fields = fields
  result.save
  end
  @rows_parsed +=1
  msg = "Saved #{@rows_parsed}"
  msg +=" of #{@rows_total}" if @rows_total.to_i > 0
  log msg
  return result
 end
 end
```

What's Wrong with this code?

Thanks